# Get ids of many-to-many entries while saving a form in Backpack Laravel

Tags: model, many-to-many, laravel-backpack

When I save a form in Backpack Laravel having a many-to-many entry field, I am not able in any way to retrieve ids in the respective model or elsewhere

I tried to retrieve ids in function booted in the model, like this:

```
    protected static function booted() {
        static::saved(function ($model) {
            dd($model);
        });
```

trying also other events such as creating, saving... the debug returned me all data of the models, but nothing about the many-to-many entered records, so I suppose the don't touch the model and are triggered elseswhere... but where?

Comment: It’s possible that the relationships are saved, and you can catch them using the method you highlighted, but it’s happening in two stages. 
First, the main table attributes and 1-n relationships, which is the one your dd() will catch. Afterwords a second save, that attaches the n-n relationships. Since you did dd() you can’t see that, because the execution is stopped in phase 1. Try dump() instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [this package](https://github.com/chelout/laravel-relationship-events) to listen to relationship events.
Please read the instructions on how to setup the package, Backpack is not affiliated with it, but I've used it many times in the past myself.

Wish you the best!